# Explanation of Array Pointers in c?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C: How come an array’s address is equal to its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/c-how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value)
>   [C pointer : array variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885027/c-pointer-array-variable)

Considering a multidimensional Array:

```
int c[1][1];
```

Why all of the following expression points to the same address??

```
printf("%x", (int *) c);      // 0x00000500
printf("%x", *c);             // 0x00000500
printf("%x", c);              // 0x00000500
```

How would a pointer's actual value and it's derefernced value can be the same?

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Comment: You are not actually dereference the pointer with *c, to dereference it you need to use `*c[0]`.  You can test this by initilizing to zero and trying the two "dereferences".

Comment: @YoussefG. Arrays decay to pointers to the first element of the array, so `c` in an expression ends up pointing to the first element, and `*c` dereferences that value

Comment: @Jason I understand what Arrays are, but in a 2d array *c is not going to give you the first value, since that only dereferences 1 address: pointer to a pointer to a character, he is getting the second pointer's address, which just so happens to be the same address as the first pointer.  Try a quick program and you will see *c will evalute to an address, but `**c` will evalute to zero (if you initilize to zero).

Comment: @YoussefG.Sorry, I guess we're saying the exact same thing ... because this is a 2D-array, `*c` dereferences to another array.  So the first element of `c` is an array, and by deferencing `c` you will return that array, but it too must decay to a pointer to its first element, which is the actual `int` element.  I was using "value" in a generic sense of whatever that type is, whether it's an array, etc., not "value" as-in the value of the `int`.

Comment: @zeronone Okay, from a compiler standpoint, `c` is a 2d-array, and it decays to a pointer to it's first "element" ... that "first element", since c is of type `int (*)[1][1]`, will be an `int (*)[1]`.  Since that first element's type is also an array-type, it too will decay to a pointer to its first element, which in this case is an `int`.

Comment: @Jason, yes makes sense now.  also, correction on my previous comment, its a pointer to an integer not a char.

Comment: @zeronone BTW, just to clear things up, here is a quick example compiled in C++ (which enforces type-saftey) of what I'm talking about: http://ideone.com/YdVDH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under most circumstances<sup>1</sup>, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

The expression `c` has type `int [1][1]`; by the rule above, the expression will decay to type `int (*)[1]`, or "pointer to 1-element array of `int`", and its value will be the same as `&c[0]`.  If we dereference this pointer (as in the expression `*c`), we get an expression of type "1-element array of `int`", which, by the rule above again, decays to an expression of type `int *`, and its value will be the same as `&c[0][0]`.

The address of the first element of the array is the same as the address of the array itself, so `&c` == `&c[0]` == `&c[0][0]` == `c` == `*c` == `c[0]`.  All of those expressions will resolve to the same address, even though they don't have the same types (`int (*)[1][1]`, `int (*)[1]`, `int *`, `int (*)[1]`, `int *`, and `int *`, respectively).

---

<sup>1 - the exceptions to this rule are when the array expression is an operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You just have to think: where is the first position on this array?

Suppose it's on `0x00000050` in your memory space. What is the first item in your array? It's `c[0][0]`, and its address is `0x00000050`. Sure enough, the address of the first position is the same of the array. Even if you do `c[0]` only, it still points to the same address, as long as you cast it to the right type.

But you should not confuse pointers to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`How would a pointer's actual value and it's derefernced value can be the same`
It's not a pointer, it's an array.

[See Q&A #3 & #4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676402/why-cant-i-treat-an-array-like-a-pointer-in-c)

`c` is the address of the array. `c` is also the address of the first element.

Comment: This answer doesn't really follow the question.  The error is in the fact that he is dereferencing only one address.  It has nothing to do with getting the address of a pointer.  c is the address of a pointer to an array of 1 integer.

Comment: @YoussefG. - The part of the OP's question that I was addressing is what I highlighted. Clearly OP is confused why a deferenced array is acting differently from a deferenced pointer (confusion regarding arrays vs. pointers)

Comment: Very loosely, I think you would be better off demonstrating the difference between 'int **c;' and 'int c[1][1];' to get that point across.